# Client side Typescript library for communicating with salesforce

Tags: javascript, rest-api, javascript-remoting, remote-objects

Just wondering if anyone has added `typings` for any of the client side javascript libraries out there?

If not, is [forcetk](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit) still the latest and greatest solution (will be using primarily for VF pages)?  Seems like it hasn't been updated in a couple years.  Want to make sure I pick the best library if I'm going to commit to manually adding typings.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a decent option so I wrote one: [ts-force](https://github.com/ChuckJonas/ts-force)

It leverages code generation to build concrete types for whatever SObjects you want to work with.

**Example:**

```js
let acc = new Account({ //all props can be set in constructor
    name: 'John Doe',
    website: 'example.com'
});
await acc.insert();
acc.name = 'Jane Doe';
await acc.update(); //passing true refreshes SObject after update

//supports relationships
let contacts = Contact.retrieve(`[SELECT Id, Name, Owner.Id, Owner.Name 
                                  FROM Contact WHERE AccountId ='${acc.id}'`);

let user = contacts[0].owner
user.email = 'john@example.com'
user.update(true) //passing true causes the user object to be refreshed
```

It currently support standard REST operations, as well as the more powerful composite API.  Plans to add bulk and other API's in the future.